# How to use lapply or purrr::map or any other fast way instead of "for loop" with lists?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply, purrr

I am calculating a index that needs a matrix of species x sites and a matrix of cophenetic distances between species (generated from a phylogenetic tree). This block of code gives the objects needed to calculate it (site and tree):

```
library(ape)#phylogenetic tree
library(picante)#ses.mpd calculation
library(purrr)#list of distance matrices

#Sample matrix
set.seed(0000)
site <- matrix(data = sample(c(0, 1), 15, prob = c(0.4, 0.6), replace = T), ncol = 5, nrow = 3)
colnames(site) <- c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5")
rownames(site) <- c("samp1", "samp2", "samp3")

#Sample phylogenetic tree
tree <- rcoal(5)

#Reordering species names in the community to match the order in the tree
site <- site[, tree$tip.label]
```

From the output above, I need to calculate `ses.mpd` 100 times using the same community matrix, but changing the distance matrix (100 of them stored in a list of 4gb). I used `for` loops to calculate `ses.mpd`, but I realised that it would take more than a month to get the output! I have used `lapply` before, but I do not know how to use it this time, neither `purrr::map`. I have seen similar questions here: [Apply a function to list of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708475/apply-a-function-to-list-of-matrices) and here:[Calculate function for all row combinations of two matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759588/calculate-function-for-all-row-combinations-of-two-matrices-in-r?rq=1), but none of them actually resembles my problem. Here is the code I used with `for` loop (updated by @Parfait). I need any other way faster than a loop to get the same output. Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

```
#Empty list for the resolved trees
many.trees <- list()

#Creates 5 resolved trees with the function ape::multi2di
for(i in 1:5){
  many.trees[[i]] <- multi2di(tree)
}

#For each resolved tree, creates a distance matrix
many.dists <- map(many.trees, cophenetic)

#ses.mpd using each of the distance matrices above
out <- list()

for(i in 1:5){
 out.2[[i]] <- ses.mpd(site, many.dists[[length(many.dists)]])# Thanks, @Parfait.
}
```

Comment: Both code blocks call different methods. What do you need help with? Which part takes so long: `multi2di`, `cophenetic`, `ses.mpd`? 4GB matrices naturally will take long.

Comment: @Parfait, thank you! I edited the question to make it clearer. I need something faster than the second loop (to get ses.mpd) in the second block to get the same output.

Comment: Your nested loop only saves the last *jth* iteration to corresponding `out[[i]]`.

Comment: @Parfait, no. In this example, it returns a list (out) with 5 data frames within that list. Each data frame contains 8 columns. One of them is the ses.mpd that I need. I just ran it right now from the very beginning and it worked fine.

Comment: Your code will run without error but your inner loop is redundant as you only save the last, jth run. Remove the inner loop and check if same results output: `for(i in 1:5) { out[[i]] <- ses.mpd(site, many.dists[[length(many.dists)]]) } `

Comment: @Parfait thanks. Your suggestion is shorter indeed, but it returned the same output. I would like to use, for example, lapply or a function from purrr or anything that could be faster than a "for loop".

Comment: That was not my suggested answer but to show you your inner loop does not effectively save all combinations of `many.dists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an *apply* family solution for more compact code and avoid bookkeeping of initializing empty lists and assigning to it.

```
# Creates 5 resolved trees with the function ape::multi2di
many.trees <- replicate(5, multi2di(tree), simplify = FALSE)   

# For each resolved tree, creates a distance matrix
many.dists <- lapply(many.trees, cophenetic)

# ses.mpd using each of the distance matrices above
out_nested <- lapply(many.dists, function(d) ses.mpd(site, d))
```

---

To retain names (if included in above methods), change `lapply` to `sapply` (equivalent to `lapply` with `simplify=FALSE` but maintains `USE.NAMES=TRUE`). The result would then be named lists.

```
# For each resolved tree, creates a distance matrix
many.dists <- sapply(many.trees, cophenetic, simplify = FALSE)

# ses.mpd using each of the distance matrices above
out <- sapply(many.dists, function(d) ses.mpd(site, d), simplify = FALSE)

out$first_name
out$second_name
out$third_name
out$fourth_name
out$fifth_name
```

Comment: thank you! It is at least twice as much quicker than the previous code.

Comment: Fantastic! Great to hear and glad to help!